# Failed to instantiate application in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

So i'am trying to learn Jetpack Compose, but my Dependency Injection with dagger hilt cannot work properly. But, it is works fine in the other project, so is there something i'am missing here?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                Process: com.lelestacia.submissioncompose, PID: 6340
                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.lelestacia.submissioncompose.application.MyApp package com.lelestacia.submissioncompose: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lelestacia.submissioncompose.application.MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.lelestacia.submissioncompose/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~UPDLbuW7-1MIDHePtZAPuw==/com.lelestacia.submissioncompose-VtqvuByd7B1W6Uwl4SYgJA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~UPDLbuW7-1MIDHePtZAPuw==/com.lelestacia.submissioncompose-VtqvuByd7B1W6Uwl4SYgJA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
                                                                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6746)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2134)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lelestacia.submissioncompose.application.MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.lelestacia.submissioncompose/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~UPDLbuW7-1MIDHePtZAPuw==/com.lelestacia.submissioncompose-VtqvuByd7B1W6Uwl4SYgJA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~UPDLbuW7-1MIDHePtZAPuw==/com.lelestacia.submissioncompose-VtqvuByd7B1W6Uwl4SYgJA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
                                                                                                    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1232)
                                                                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458)
                                                                                                    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6746) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2134) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898) 
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
                                                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/lelestacia/submissioncompose/application/Hilt_MyApp;
                                                                                                        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                                                                                                        ... 16 more
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.lelestacia.submissioncompose.application.Hilt_MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.lelestacia.submissioncompose/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~UPDLbuW7-1MIDHePtZAPuw==/com.lelestacia.submissioncompose-VtqvuByd7B1W6Uwl4SYgJA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~UPDLbuW7-1MIDHePtZAPuw==/com.lelestacia.submissioncompose-VtqvuByd7B1W6Uwl4SYgJA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        ... 19 more
```

And java generated also didn't generate my viewmodel factory, and my app module still marked as unused function even tho it has the icon of consumed from dagger hilt.

Comment: Have you tried `invalidate cache/restart`?, or deleting `.idea` and/or `.gradle` then re-importing the project?

Comment: Yes already did that, but still not working

Comment: Have you created a application class ?
If yes ensure that it is public & its name is added in application tag in Android Manifest

Comment: its working after i invalidate the project, might be a bug